# .txt to vector<struct> fault

Tags: c++, input, vector, struct

I am currently finishing my exam project for school. I am to create a userdatabase, where you can login via an account and write messages to others in the system. But there is several bugs, I haven't found until now. When the program is first executed, it will copy the user database into a .txt format, like this (userlist.txt),

```
created: Sun May 13 18:41:08 2012
mod_date: Sun May 13 18:41:08 2012


ID:1
created:Sun May 13 18:41:08 2012
name:admin
password:Admin1
security level:2
status:active
```

This works fine, since it was copied from a vector. But then I have to do the reverse process, when I open the program for the secondth time (Unless I deleted userlist.txt), and the vector seems to hold wrong information. It is hard to explain, and therefore I uploaded the source code to mediafire. I guess there is a total of 600 lines of code, but I only think main.cpp and the functions login() and writedb() inside of dbmani.h (Where the vector is defined inside a class) are necessary to see the problem. The first lines in the code are here (Where the vector will receive input from the userlist.txt if it exists), in hope that you don't have to download all of my source code,

```
int main()
{

    system("mkdir messages");
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("userlist.txt");


    if(inFile.good())   // If userlist.txt exist - therefore an existing user database exist.
    {
        // ADD DATE OF MODIFICATION
        cout << "USERLIST FOUND, READING USERS.\n\n";
        userstats tempBuffer;
        int userCount = -1;
        int overCount = 0;
        string buffer;

        while(getline(inFile, buffer))
        {
            if (0 == buffer.find("ID:"))
            {
                userCount++;

                if (userCount > overCount)
                {

                    userbase.users.push_back(tempBuffer);
                    overCount++;

                }
                buffer.erase(0, 3);
                tempBuffer.ID = buffer;

            }
            else if (0 == buffer.find("created:"))
            {

                buffer.erase(0, 8);
                tempBuffer.date = buffer;

            }
            else if (0 == buffer.find("name:"))
            {

                buffer.erase(0, 5);
                tempBuffer.name = buffer;

            }
            else if (0 == buffer.find("password:"))
            {
                buffer.erase(0, 9);
                tempBuffer.password = buffer;
            }
            else if (0 == buffer.find("status:"))
            {
                buffer.erase(0,7);
                if (buffer == "active")
                    tempBuffer.active = true;
                else if (buffer == "inactive")
                    tempBuffer.active = false;
            }



        }
        if (userCount == 0)
        {
            userbase.users.push_back(tempBuffer);
        }

        inFile.close();
    }
    else    // If no userlist.txt exists, create new one from vector. This instance works, but there is only one user
    {
        cout << "NO USERS FOUND, CREATING NEW LIST.\n";
        inFile.close();

        // Determine current date
        time_t rawtime;
        struct tm * timeinfo;

        time (&rawtime );
        timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
        string cdate = asctime(timeinfo);

        userstats userBuffer = {"1", cdate, "admin", "Admin1", admin, 1};
        userbase.users.push_back(userBuffer);

        ofstream outFile("userlist.txt");



        outFile << "created: " << cdate;
        outFile << "mod_date: " << cdate << "\n\n";
        outFile << "ID:" << userbase.users[0].ID << "\n";
        outFile << "created:" << userbase.users[0].date;
        outFile << "name:" << userbase.users[0].name << "\n";
        outFile << "password:"<< userbase.users[0].password << "\n";
        outFile << "security level:" << userbase.users[0].secLev << "\n";
        outFile << "status:active\n\n";


        outFile.close();
    }

    // CHECK DIR
    char ch;
    cout << "Choices are listed below\n";
    cout << "1) login\t2) Register an Account\n"
         << "q) Quit.\n";
    cout << "Select option: ";

    bool breakFlag = false;
    while (breakFlag == false && cin.get(ch))
    {
        cin.ignore();
        // Could use getch to eliminate errors instead.

        switch (ch)
        {
            case '1':   int logID;
                        logID = userbase.login();
                        if (logID)
                        {
                            logID -= 1;
                            loggedin(logID);
                        }
    ...
```

Also, if I registered a second account, "admina", with regAcc() inside dbmani.h, I noticed my userlist would look like this (And creating a third account will override the second),

```
created: Sun May 13 18:41:08 2012
mod_date: Sun May 13 19:08:01 2012


ID:1
created:Sun May 13 18:41:08 2012name:admin
password:Admin1
status:active

ID:2
created:Sun May 13 19:08:01 2012
name:admina
password:Admin1
security level:0
status:active
```

Here is the source code, if you prefer it:
http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?6dp6sxn952j7s37

I would be so grateful if anyone would spent some time helping me, if only with the ".txt to vector" problem, since I am running out of time, and I really can't see the error(s). I tried looking the web, but I didn't seem to find anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the zipped code, a few things jump out at me:

1) You are searching for the string 'created', but you'll find that at the very start of the file, which is not part of a record and will give a false positive

2) At the end of reading the .txt file, it doesn't look like you add the last record to your vector of records (unless the total number of users is 0, which seems unlikely)

3) tempBuffer is never cleared, so if record 4 has a created date, and record 5 doesn't, record 5 will be stored with record 4's created date.

I would be inclined to read an entire record in at once when 'ID:' is found, so something like:

```
if (0 == buffer.find("ID:"))
{
    tempBuffer.ID = buffer.substr(3);
    if (!getline(inFile, buffer) || buffer.find("created:") != 0)
    {
        cerr << "Error reading record for ID" << tempBuffer.ID << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    tempBuffer.date = buffer.substr(8);
    // ...etc

    userbase.users.push_back(tempBuffer);
}
```

Hopefully this would help weed out errors in file formatting as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped me understand a few things, and I got to learn about .substr(), which I think I could use in other parts of my code. Your code works, very well, but I think it somewhat removes the elements of the vector it has just pushed back when going out of the while scope (I implemented your code inside the while loop of my code, and the elements only exist here). I have never thought of this, and maybe it is the reason for my errors.